# *ngFor next element

Tags: html, angular-cli

I am using Angular Cli. So, my html is:

```
<div *ngFor="let Item of Items" (click)="add("*next Item should be here*")"></div>
```

I need to send to function add() not Item but the next element. How I can call;it?
And I should stop when the arrow is end in order not to go out of the array

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What is the use-case? What happens if there is no next item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `Items` is an array or indexed collection you can use the special `index` variable and pass that to your function:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" (click)="add( i )">
```

Then inside your `add` function you would check the index:

```
add(index: number): void {

    let nextIndex = index + 1;
    if( nextIndex < this.items.length ) {
        // do stuff
    }
    else {
        // error: there is no next-item
    }
}
```

This is documented here: https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

> - `index: number` - The index of the current item in the iterable.
> - `first: boolean` - True when the item is the first item in the iterable.
> - `last: boolean` - True when the item is the last item in the iterable.
> - `even: boolean` - True when the item has an even index in the iterable.
> - `odd: boolean` - True when the item has an odd index in the iterable.